# How to rectify the type of null in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, api, angular8

In my Angular application, I call several APIs for user, super user and admin.

For a particular user type, it has to got to the dashboard (user dashboard, super user, admin).

**.service.ts:**

```
public errors: any = [];
public  userprof: any;
type: any;

datalog = {
     location : "lat: "+localStorage.getItem('lt')+",lng:"+localStorage.getItem('lt'),
     action : "Dashboard View",
     login_status: 1
}

//After login I have to call the profile API i.e below

public login(user) {
    this.http.post(environment.apiUrl+'/api/login', JSON.stringify(user), this.httpOptions).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.updateData(data['token']);
        localStorage.setItem('token',data['token']);
        
        var jsons=this.dashboardService.create('',this.token);
        this.userprofile();

let userprof = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));
          let httpOptions = {
              headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                //'Authorization': 'Token ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
                'Authorization': 'Token ' + this.token

              })
            };
            if(userprof.usertype === 'Admin'){
          
               this.http.post(environment.apiUrl+'/api/activity/adminsession',JSON.stringify(this.datalog), httpOptions).subscribe(
              (dataforlogin1)=>{
          console.log(dataforlogin1);
               },
              err=>{
                console.log("Error",err)
              }
            
            );
          }
           else if(userprof.usertype === 'Super User'){
                this.http.post(environment.apiUrl+'/api/activity/superusersession',JSON.stringify(this.datalog), httpOptions).subscribe(
                (dataforlogin2)=>{
            console.log(dataforlogin2);
                 
                },
                err=>{
                  console.log("Error",err)
                }
              );
          
            }
            else{
               this.http.post(environment.apiUrl+'/api/activity/usersession',JSON.stringify(this.datalog), httpOptions).subscribe(
                (dataforlogin3)=>{
            console.log(dataforlogin3);
                 
                },
                err=>{
                  console.log("Error",err)
                }
              
              );
            }
          },

 userprofile() {
              let httpOptions = {
                headers: new HttpHeaders({
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                  'Authorization': 'Token ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
                })
              };
              this.http.get(environment.apiUrl+'/profile', httpOptions).subscribe(
                (profile:any)=>{
            
                 localStorage.setItem("profile",JSON.stringify(profile));
                 console.log("profile:",JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("profile")))
                 
            
                 if(profile.usertype==="Admin"){
                   
                  this.router.navigate(['/admin']);
              
              }
              else if(profile.usertype==="Super User"){
              this.router.navigate(['/superuser']);
              }
              else{
              this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
              }
                },
                err=>{
                  console.log("Error",err)
                }
              );
              }
```

It is working but when I remove the localstorage in developer tools, it is not showing the dashboard data and showing the error is:

> Cannot read property 'usertype' of null
> at SafeSubscriber.http.post.subscribe.errors

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: You might wanna check, if `profile` has some data or it's not null, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

using the below code, you'll be able to enter into the else if userProf is null

```
if(userprof.usertype && userprof.usertype === 'Admin'){
          
               this.http.post(environment.apiUrl+'/api/activity/adminsession',JSON.stringify(this.datalog), httpOptions).subscribe(
              (dataforlogin1)=>{
          console.log(dataforlogin1);
               },
              err=>{
                console.log("Error",err)
              }
            
            );
          }
           else if(userprof.usertype && userprof.usertype === 'Super User'){
                this.http.post(environment.apiUrl+'/api/activity/superusersession',JSON.stringify(this.datalog), httpOptions).subscribe(
                (dataforlogin2)=>{
            console.log(dataforlogin2);
                 
                },
                err=>{
                  console.log("Error",err)
                }
              );
          
            }
```